# gcc don't respect hierarchy of include files

Tags: gcc, include, g++

I used the word hierarchy, but I'm not sure if it's the right one! Let me explain.

I have A.h with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

I have B.h with:

```
typedef vector<int> int_vector;
int_vector my_function(int x, int y);
```

Finally I have X.h, which is:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
```

And X.cpp:

```
#include "X.h"

// and the rest
```

But when I compile that with GCC, it says in B.h, vector not defined and so on. Note that this is an example to explain the problem. The project I'm trying to convert to compile on linux compiles perfectly on Windows under Visual Studio.

I could change the files, but it a 300+ files project, so any help or suggestion that would be incredibly efficient ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code that you've posted, and it seems unlikely that there would be a bug of this nature in `gcc`.

More likely the problem isn't what it seems. For example, it could be that there are multiple `A.h` (or `B.h`, or `X.h`) files in your project, and the wrong file is being included somewhere.

My advice would be to run one problematic `.cpp` file through the preprocessor (`gcc -E`) and examine the result. That will tell you exactly what is being included when.

Comment: the error was stupid. In some #if #else #endif part, a bloc of code was closing earlier a parenthesis for a namespace... which cause to steve everything up! Normally, it would have suppose to compile. I used that approach before. And it's common with OpenGL (at least one version)